# Extjs Set dirty false for form after saving

Tags: extjs4.2, sencha-touch-2.1

I need to reset the form's dirty status to false after saving the form.

Form is configured for trackresetonload so that not set dirty for setvalue function.

I tried calling reset() but it resets the data in the form fields to its previous state(ie initial value).

Is there a way to do this,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
formpanel.setValues(formpanel.getValues());
```

Aafter you call this, the form has not longer the dirty status